# VOLTTRON 4.1 Historian Topic Targeting, and Permissions Comment

Tags: volttron

I have one question and one comment about VOLTTRON 4.1:

**Question: In the new 4.1 Historian, is there a way to limit the topics that are picked up by the historian?** Previously, there were config options "topic_list" and "all_data," and using them allowed me to limit the historian database to only recording topics from certain devices. Our end-goal here is to have a few separate databases, each recording data from a different class of specific devices (i.e. a building temperature database, a solar measurement database, etc.). My current plan on how to realize this is to start multiple historian agents, each configured to a specific database and targeted to specific topics.

**Comment: When starting our new VOLTTRON 4.1 MySQL historian, we at first had an incorrect user/password credential in our config file. However, the error we saw did not notify us of this**: instead, we got an error in mysqlfuncts.init_microsecond_support() as the agent was attempting to query the database for its version before it notified us that the credentials were incorrect. The query failed because it didn't have permissions, but debugging the issue took considerable time. I just wanted to inform you of this, as it would have been helpful to receive an "access denied."

Here was our error log:

```
ERROR: Exception in thread Thread-2:
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
ERROR:     self.run()
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
ERROR:     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
ERROR:   File "/home/uw/volttron_new/volttron/platform/agent/base_historian.py", line 707, in _process_loop
ERROR:     self.historian_setup()
ERROR:   File "/home/uw/volttron_new/volttron/utils/docs.py", line 47, in f
ERROR:     return self.mthd(obj, *args, **kwargs)
ERROR:   File "/home/uw/.volttron/agents/c05aba11-24da-4bf5-bc1a-3561da4f30bf/sqlhistorianagent-3.6.1/sqlhistorian/historian.py", line 355, in historian_setup
ERROR:     self.writer.setup_historian_tables()
ERROR:   File "/home/uw/volttron_new/volttron/platform/dbutils/mysqlfuncts.py", line 113, in setup_historian_tables
ERROR:     self.init_microsecond_support()
ERROR:   File "/home/uw/volttron_new/volttron/platform/dbutils/mysqlfuncts.py", line 101, in init_microsecond_support
ERROR:     version_nums = p.match(rows[0][0]).groups()
ERROR: IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confusing the SQLHistorian with the ForwardHistorian https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/blob/develop/services/core/ForwardHistorian/config

The forward historian is the only agent that has ever "filtered" what gets sent across the wire.

If you would like that feature to extend to other historians please submit an issue and/or take a look at extending the base_historian to do this from the configuration file.

As for the second thing you mentioned, would you please post that as an issue and we can probably take care of that rather quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In that case, I'll probably edit the historian agent code so that I can make dedicated databases that subscribe to specific topics.

How do I submit the error as an issue? Is that on this site or GitHub?